# Bootstrap Tooltips Not Working Inside nav nav-sidebar class

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, nav, sidebar

Tooltips are working fine when it's like this

```
    <li>
        <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Some tooltip text!" class="sidebar-item-link">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home glyph-sidebar"></span>
            <span class="sidebar-text">Home</span>
        </a>
    </li>
```

But once I nest it inside a 'ul' with class nav and nav-sidebar, the tooltip no longer shows.

e.g.

```
<ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
    <li>
        <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Some tooltip text!" class="sidebar-item-link">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home glyph-sidebar"></span>
            <span class="sidebar-text">Home</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I couldn't find the answer to this anywhere. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/43/

**HTML**

```
<ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
    <li>
        <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Some tooltip text!" class="sidebar-item-link" data-placement="bottom">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home glyph-sidebar"></span>
            <span class="sidebar-text">Home</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! But it didn't work. When I hover over it and inspect element, I can see that the div tooltip class is coming up, but the tooltip still does not show on the actual page. Any ideas? Could it be a clash somewhere?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/d3h3pjfo/

The ul is nested inside a div with class 'sidebar'

Comment: Thankyou! Got it working now. I realised it just doesn't work when I try to make it appear on the right. But I guess that's a question for another thread!

Comment: I think that's because your nav is fullwidth to the right and you have `overflow:hidden` on body so its shows just out of window. Take a look at this https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/49/

Comment: You're right! overflow:hidden was the problem. Thank-you so much

Comment: No problem, glad i could help.